# Designing compatible spur gears for a robot gearbox

Tags: motor, differential-drive

I'm trying to increase the torque on the output shaft of my robot's gearbox.  I have a motor with a pinion attached to it with 8 teeth.  I want to create a gear with 33 teeth that will mesh with the pinion that I currently have.  I've got access to a 3D printer to make the gear, but I don't know how to design the second gear so that it will mesh properly.

What parameters do I need to know about the first gear (8 teeth) to ensure that the second gear (33 teeth) will mesh correctly?  How do I translate these parameters into the design of the second gear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make compatible gears, you need to match the pitch and shape of the teeth.

First, check out [this wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gear) about gears and especially [the image about nomenclature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gear#Nomenclature), so you have a good idea of the names for things:

[image: Gear Nomenclature]

You first need to determine the pitch of the gear you want to match, the 8-tooth gear. If it has a diameter of say 10 mm, then take the circumference for your new gear (πd = 31.4 mm) and divide by the number of teeth (8) to get a pitch of 3.925 mm. Note that I am using the root circle to calculate diameter, rather than outside circle.

Knowing the pitch, multiply by 33 to get the circumference: 129.525 mm. We can now determine the diameter (d = c / π), 41.25 mm.

You'll need to use the same tooth shape, that is, the angles for the faces and flanks of the teeth, so that the gears mesh well.